# Delete dictionary item if its key contains word

Tags: python

I have this dictionary:

```
a={'sting1':1,'string2':2,'string3':3,'string4 null':4}
```

I want to delete items where key contains word null.

```
output={'sting1':1,'string2':2,'string3':3}
```

I found startswith application, and tried to work with key.find('null')!=-1 , but that didn't work out

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do `dictionary comprehension`:

```
print({k:v for k,v in a.items() if not 'null' in k})
```

If version below 2.6:

```
print(dict((k,v) for k,v in a.iteritems() if not 'null' in k))
```

See `iteritems`, not `items`, that's in python 2 only (all of python 2 versions)

"You can also write if 'null' not in k which some people find easier to read", thanks to @john.

Comment: You can also write `if 'null' not in k` which some people find easier to read

Answer (score 1):

In Python, to check if a string is contained in another string you can simply use the `in` keyword like this:

```
if "null" in "something null bla bla":
    # null is in the string
```

To delete all the items that contain null you can therefore simply loop over them, check if they contain null and remove them if they do:

```
for key in list(a.keys()):
    if "null" in key:
        del a[key]
```

Note that we have to create a list of all the keys, otherwise we can't remove items from the dict while iterating.

If you want to create a new dict with the items removed you can use a `dict comprehension` as the other answer shows or just use a plain old for loop:

```
output = {}
for key, value in a.items():
    if "null" not in key:
        # key is ok => add to output
        output[key] = value
```

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done in-place:

```
l = []
for k in a:
    if 'null' in k:
        l.append(k)

for k in l:
    del a[k]
```

Or not:

```
b = {}
for k in a:
    if 'null' not in k:
       b[k] = a[k]
```